# NSArrayController , arrangedObjects and tableColumn IB connection

Tags: macos, xcode4, nsdictionary, nstableview, nsarraycontroller

I am new to mac development. I am trying to make [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/DictionaryController/Introduction/Intro.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10004522) app from apple.com
At one point i am stucked in interface builder.

[image]

How do i connect `arrangedObjects.firstName` to the `Value - Table Column - First Name` and `Last Name`?

Edit:
this is my array controller and its bindings.

[image]

Thank you in advance..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ctrl Shift click with a mouse  on a column in your table (NOT column's header). You should see the list of views which are parent to each other:

[image]

Select `NSTableColumn` view. Then just open bindings tab and perform same procedure as with arrangedObjects' binding.

Comment: I can't found binding tab.. I am very new to all this.. Can u please tell me in detail?

Comment: It's in same place where you bound the arrangedObjects value for your nsarraycontroller

Comment: but i can't bound arrangedObjects to my nsarraycontroller.. let me edit my question and show you my new app's nsarraycontroller and its bindings..

Comment: it's the last tab in interface builder's inspector panel. or second last in xcode4's utility bar